# PHP: How to compare WordPress versions?

Tags: php, wordpress

Interesting problem happen to me today where I'm not able to compare 2 versions of WordPress installations.

> NOTE: I want to compare WordPress versions, not PHP versions.

I try example like this:

```
if(version_compare(get_bloginfo('version'),'3.5') >= 0)
    echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5';
else
    echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
```

Where I made mistake?

I getting -1 and need 1 for WordPress version 4.7.2 what `get_bloginfo()` return.

I use in local PHP7 but my clients will use PHP5.6, PHP5.4 or nevermind.

Comment: _“Where I made mistake?”_ – in not telling us what the result of your test was? In not actually describing what the _problem_ is?

Comment: *"I use in local PHP7 but my clients will use PHP5.6, PHP5.4 or nevermind."* Make your development/test environment match production, or at least provide backwards compatibility. A lot of things have changed in PHP7 from PHP5

Comment: @CBroe OK I getting `-1` and need `1` WordPress version is `4.7.2`

Comment: @hd well `version_compare()` is not changed and existing since PHP4

Comment: And you have of course checked what `get_bloginfo('version')` returns?

Comment: @CBroe return `4.7.2` I chacked

Comment: `version_compare('4.7.2','3.5')` returns `1` under almost every PHP version imaginable, see https://3v4l.org/P4ks6 (and a test of _that_ line on your system should presumably return the same) - so there must be something about your code we don’t know about yet.

Comment: @CBroe I literally copy/past my test. It just boggles my mind why not show well. In same file I `var_dump()` `get_bloginfo('version')` and `version_compare(get_bloginfo('version'),'3.5')` and get `4.7.2`, `-1` what confuse me a lot. I test manualy and get same results. But when add `version_compare(get_bloginfo('version'),'3.5.0')` get `1` - just test. Why happen like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this code :

```
if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '3.5', '>=' ) ) {
   echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5';
} else {
   echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Although answered, it is worthwhile to note that the current installed version can also be retrieved by the `$wp_version` global variable.

```
global $wp_version;

if ( version_compare($wp_version,'3.5') >= 0) {
    echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5';
} else {
    echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
}
```

Also, considering that the version is assigned to `$wp_version` within `/wp-includes/version.php` which is subsequently required from `/wp-load.php` — said variable is already in the global scope, so you could omit the `global $wp_version` however your IDE may complain (so not necessarily recommended).

```
if ( version_compare($wp_version,'3.5') >= 0) {
    echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5';
} else {
    echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
}
```

...or alternatively:

```
if ( version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'],'3.5') >= 0) {
    echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5';
} else {
    echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
}
```

Interestingly in `/wp-admin/update-core.php` WordPress calls `get_bloginfo('version')` in functions:

- `list_core_update`
- `core_upgrade_preamble`
- `list_plugin_updates`
- `after_core_update`

...if a call to  `get_bloginfo('version')` is also supplied a second argument with value `display` such as:

- `get_bloginfo('version', 'display')`

...then the value is also filterable via:

- `add_filter( 'bloginfo_url', 'your_callback' )`

...which is worthy to note in the event the version returned is modified before use and whereby you are reliant upon a precise and accurate version reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way

```
 if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.5', '>=' ) ) {
     echo 'Wordpress Version same or above 3.5'; 
 } 
 else{
     echo 'Wordpress Version below 3.5';
 }
```